# opencv4nodejs подключение в nodejs проект

Tags: node.js, opencv, npm, распознавание-символов

Версия ноды 10.19.0

Провел установку и билд opencv4 на Ubuntu 20.04. Для этого юзал [данный](http://www.codebind.com/cpp-tutorial/install-opencv-ubuntu-cpp/) гайд.
В результате имею собраный билд opencv4 на компе
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После `npm install --save opencv4nodejs` в проекте получил ошибку. Текст прилогаю

```
info install spawning node gyp process: node-gyp rebuild --jobs max
make: Entering directory '/home/yuriygalay/Documents/Big Brother/big-brother/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/opencv4nodejs/cc/opencv4nodejs.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/opencv4nodejs/cc/CustomMatAllocator.o
g++: error: Brother/big-brother/node_modules/native-node-utils/src: No such file or directory
make: *** [opencv4nodejs.target.mk:246: Release/obj.target/opencv4nodejs/cc/opencv4nodejs.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
g++: error: Brother/big-brother/node_modules/native-node-utils/src: No such file or directory
make: *** [opencv4nodejs.target.mk:246: Release/obj.target/opencv4nodejs/cc/CustomMatAllocator.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/home/yuriygalay/Documents/Big Brother/big-brother/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/share/nodejs/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.8.0-53-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild" "--jobs" "max"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/yuriygalay/Documents/Big Brother/big-brother/node_modules/opencv4nodejs
gyp ERR! node -v v10.19.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v6.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
ERR! Error: Command failed: node-gyp rebuild --jobs max
g++: error: Brother/big-brother/node_modules/native-node-utils/src: No such file or directory
make: *** [opencv4nodejs.target.mk:246: Release/obj.target/opencv4nodejs/cc/opencv4nodejs.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
g++: error: Brother/big-brother/node_modules/native-node-utils/src: No such file or directory
make: *** [opencv4nodejs.target.mk:246: Release/obj.target/opencv4nodejs/cc/CustomMatAllocator.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/share/nodejs/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.8.0-53-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild" "--jobs" "max"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/yuriygalay/Documents/Big Brother/big-brother/node_modules/opencv4nodejs
gyp ERR! node -v v10.19.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v6.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

После запуска проекта получил ошибку `Cannot find module '/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/build/Release/opencv4nodejs'`
Из ошибки понятно, что невозможно сбилдить opencv4nodejs.
Вопрос... Как это решить? Не понимаю. Буду рад любым советам

PS: Гуглил, не помогло, именно поэтому я здесь

UPD
После советов из комметарииев получил следующую ошибку...

```
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:353:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:376:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.8.0-53-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild" "--jobs" "max"
```

Comment: установите более современную версию nodejs, 14 или 16

Comment: @nörbörnën Помогло, но ошибка сейчас другая.
```Error: Cannot find module 'nopt'
Require stack:
- /usr/share/nodejs/node-gyp/lib/node-gyp.js
- /usr/share/nodejs/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js
```

Comment: 1) удалите lock-файл и локальные node_modules 2) заново установи node_gyp по гайдам из его репы 3) повтори установку opencv4nodejs

Comment: @nörbörnën новая ошибка, обновил вопрос

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60482583/4496422 и https://stackoverflow.com/a/52673931/4496422